# Android GPS location isn't as accurate as network location

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I've got an app which sets up two location listeners (one for GPS and one for network) and then chooses the location from the best one available, which should be GPS. However, if GPS is turned on, it will always choose the GPS location, even if the person starts the app up indoors. This has led to the GPS location being used even if the last known GPS location is from miles away and the network location is actually much more accurate.

Is there any way around this issue or is it just something that will need to be accepted as an issue with using GPS & network? Is the standard practice just to assume that GPS is always more accurate even though it's possible that it might not be in certain instances?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the network provider to fetch the location they are not very accurate when compared to GPS. So it can be a good idea to fetch the accuracy of your position using network provider when you are indoors as GPS doesnt function well indoors and you can use GPS to get the location updates when you are outdoor.

You can use GetAccuracy() method of Location class and see for the value it returns. Let Say if  getAccuracy() retruns 25 then you can leave this value wait for another gps value until you get the desired value. Remember the value it returns is the radius of the circle in meters.